# AWS Lambda does not reinitialize new Variables and uses previous execution values

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am Deploying an AWS Lambda Function that does numeric calculations, but when I deploy the function it runs correctly for the first time, then it takes the previous values and recalculates everything based on previous values. (I am calculating percentage with this function, in the first execution it calculates 50.34% which is correct but when I run this function again, it shows 0.69%, also when I try to run it thrice it shows -49.34%, and so on.) This is the major problem I am facing, it should reinitialize the variables from scratch. When I try to run the same function in my local machine in VS Code or in CMD this thing does not happen. Language: NodeJS 12.x and the same thing happen with NodeJS 14.x. This thing happens in Lambda Console and in API Gateway. Also, this function is triggered with API Gateway same thing and the same results are shown in console and postman. All the cache options in API Gateway are turned off.

My Code works like this:

```
exports.handler = function(event) {
    var foo = 39600;
    var bar = 86400;
    var result = await MyLambdaFunction (foo, bar);

    return {
       "results":result
    }
}

let doo = 23.2255;
async function MyLambdaFunction (foo, bar) {
    myPercentage = ((foo+doo)/bar)*100;
    return myPercentage;
}
```

foo and bar values are passed, but lambda takes previous results and returns those. How to prevent this?

Comment: This code ALWAYS returns the same value since `foo`, `bar` and `doo` are constant anyway. Lambda is not "at fault" here. This code behaves the same inside and outside a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this works OK in VSCode or on the command line is that every time I am running it, I am starting a new Node process, running the function, and then trashing the entire Node process at the end, and thus starting with new globals each time I run it. No problem so far, but when I try to run it in Lambda it does not work. Here's why,

Lambda Functions are kept in the memory of the server. What this means is declaring variable out handler or any function will be kept as it was. Which means it will have previous values. This should be solved if we move the variable doo inside the MyLambdaFunction function.

```
async function MyLambdaFunction (foo, bar) {
    let doo = 23.2255;
    myPercentage = ((foo+doo)/bar)*100;
    return myPercentage;
}
```

This will fix the problem. So in conclusion, one should not declare variables outside the functions. If you want to have constants, lambda provides environments, using them will work.

Comment: This appears to be a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67866934/aws-lambda-uses-old-variables-instead-of-reinitialize-new-variables and the code you have shown still does not really demonstrate lambda storing values since storing constants in a global scope does not matter since they are constant and do not carry any state anyway. Your example is still too basic and is missing the "problematic" parts of the code. And it is perfectly fine to carry state in global variables, e.g. to enable best-effort caching or keeping database or other sessions alive across different executions.